# Is there any way I can better this WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way I can change the multiple or statements into a smaller chunk? I want to avoid this getting out of hand. I tried

```
retail = 1 AND attribute IN ()
```

but doesn't seems to give the same results

```
WHERE 
tDate BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-11-30 00:00:00'
AND  (
    (retail = 1 AND attribute = 2453)
    OR (retail = 1 AND attribute = 2454)
    OR (retail = 1 AND attribute = 2455)
    OR (retail = 1 AND attribute = 2456)
    OR (retail = 1 AND attribute = 2457)
    OR (retail = 1 AND attribute = 2458)
    OR (retail = 1 AND attribute = 2459)
    OR (retail = 1 AND attribute = 2460)
    OR (retail = 1 AND attribute = 2461)
    OR (retail = 1 AND attribute = 2463)
    OR (retail = 1 AND attribute = 2464)
    OR (retail = 1 AND attribute = 2465)
    OR (retail = 1 AND attribute = 2466)
    OR (retail = 1 AND attribute = 2467)
    OR (retail = 1 AND attribute = 2468)
    OR (retail = 1 AND attribute = 2469)
    OR (retail = 1 AND attribute = 2470)
    OR (retail = 1 AND attribute = 3887)
)
```

Comment: "_I tried [...] but doesn't seems to give the same results_" Why not? What results _does_ it give??

Comment: With the above statement, i get 196606880.34 and with IN I get 146522946.92. So my guess is some values are not coming through

Comment: This was a screw up by my colleague on the data side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be equivalent:

```
WHERE tDate BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-11-30' AND
      retail = 1 AND
      attribute IN (2453, 2454, . . .)
```

The `. . .` is for the remaining values.

If your results look different, it is probably just the ordering of the result set.  You might want to include an `ORDER BY` to be sure the results are in some canonical order.

Note:  I would discourage your from using `BETWEEN` with date/time data.  If you want everything through midnight on Nov 29th, then use:

```
WHERE tDate >= '2019-01-01' AND 
      tDate < '2019-11-30' AND
      retail = 1 AND
      attribute IN (2453, 2454, . . .)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the IN operator.

```
WHERE [tDate] BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-11-30 00:00:00'
   AND ( [Retail] = 1 AND [Attribute] IN (2453, 2454, ... , 3887) )
```